# Is there a correct way to do dua after salaah? (Sunni, Hanafi, Deobandi viewpoint)

Tags: sunni, dua, hanafi

Is there a correct way to perform dua after salaah?

I have been told that, if you do not mention the prophet of Islam in your dua's, your dua does not get accepted apparently. I'm Not sure if this is true or not.

So my question basically is, is there a structured way to offer a dua with certain outlined dua's which should be recited after salaah?

I am looking for the Sunni > Hanafi > Deobandi view point.

Answer (score -2):

Make Dua in Sujood during Salah. It's mentioned in Sahih Muslim Hadith#1083 and many more. Other than that recite the Tasbih of Allah and then send blessings upon the Prophet (pbuh) then make Dua. In Sha ALLAH Allah will answer your prayers.

Answer (score -3):

Bismillah-Hirrahman-ir-Raheem
First of you can make Dua whenever, you want. But among the most favored Dua Times is after farad (Obligatory) Salah. You should start with Darood on the prophet and then you should pray for His Blessings. The best are the Duas from Quran. Secondly from Hadith and thridly from sahaba and others. You can request for His Blessings and Mercies in every language. Almighty is always near His slave. May Almighty give us strength to follow our Prophet (SAW) . Amen

Comment: You should provide references for anything you said in your answer